# Laravel mail will not receive by gmail users

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-mail

When I send email by laravel `non-gmail` accounts **will receive** emails but `Gmail accounts` **will not**, does anyone here faced such problem before? **any idea what causes that?**

> As my emails are receiving with half of the users I don't think the issue is my code but just in case i share it here as well.

`Observe`

```
class SellerObserve
{
    public function created(Seller $seller)
    {
        Mail::to($seller->email)->send(new SellersWelcome($seller));
    }
}
```

`mail`

```
class SellersWelcome extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $seller;

    public function __construct(Seller $seller)
    {
        $this->seller = $seller;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('Welcome')->markdown('emails.sellers.welcome');
    }
}
```

`env`

```
MAIL_MAILER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=MY_SERVER_IP
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=MY_EMAIL_ADDRESS
MAIL_PASSWORD=MY_EMAIL_PASSWORD
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=MY_EMAIL_ADDRESS
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Comment: Sorry did you meant that **gmail** accounts are not getting your 'welcome' e-mails and others do? If so -since your `SellersWelcome` class looks perfectly fine-, it appears to be a problem with your mailer provider. ¿Have you tested with other e-mail provider? Gmail for example, no need to have G Suite for that.

Comment: @FerToasted yes you understood my point correctly, and yes I also tested with gmail provider (not G-suit) either way other providers such as yahoo, outlook will receive emails but gmail users will not.

Comment: There is a scoring system for email servers to protect users from spams and phishings. It could be that your email server has a low score so your emails are rejected. If that's the case, the other email servers will reject your emails in the future as well. You could try sending emails via other email services instead.

Comment: @AnuratChapanond thank you solved it and shared the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've changed my mail settings to GMAIL (my sender will be gmail instead of my hosting) and then I've turned on less security from account settings, now it sends emails to all providers including gmail users.

`env`

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=MY_EMAIL_ADDRESS
MAIL_PASSWORD=MY_EMAIL_PASSWORD
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=MY_EMAIL_ADDRESS
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

[image: one]

Comment: Thank you so much, I was starting to see this problem as spiritual.

Answer (score -1):

To help keep your account secure, from May 30, 2022, ​​Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password.

Important: This deadline does not apply to Google Workspace or Google Cloud Identity customers. The enforcement date for these customers will be announced on the Workspace blog at a later date.

For more information, continue to read

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).